How to Assign Where to Paste Data and Not Just in the Very Last Empty Column
The code I have written below copy-pastes data from other workbooks into the first column that has nothing after it. So, my macro will only paste the data in the first column that has only empty columns after it however, I am trying to paste this data into a column that may have data in the column after it. How can I assign a starting column for my data to go into and then the following data in the next workbook goes into the next column? For instance, I have 20 files I am importing data from and I want them to paste starting in column E of my worksheet and continue pasting into the next consecutive column. Also, some of the items I am copying may have blank cells and I want them to paste as "0".
Sub Avg_Rate_Changes_Import()
    
    Dim FileNameXls, f        
    Dim wb As Workbook, I As Integer
    
    FileNameXls = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        filefilter:="Excel Files, *.xl*", MultiSelect:=True)
    
    If Not IsArray(FileNameXls) Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each f In FileNameXls        
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(f)
    
        For I = 1 To 1
          
            wb.Worksheets("Avg Rate Changes").Range("G9:G21").Copy
            
            lastColumn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Avg Rate Changes ").Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            
            Set pasteRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Avg Rate Changes").Cells(4, lastColumn + 1)
            pasteRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Avg Rate Changes")            
                Set pasteRange = .Range(.Cells(4, lastColumn + 1), .Cells(16, lastColumn + 1 + 6))                        
                pasteRange.Replace What:="", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlWhole        
            End With    
        Next I        
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False        
    Next f
    Application.CutCopyMode = False        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True        
End Sub


Use CountA function to check for empty column
Option Explicit

Sub Avg_Rate_Changes_Import()

    Dim FileNameXls, f, v, n As Long, i As Long
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet, targetColumn As Long
    Dim wbSource As Workbook, arData
    
    ' select source files
    FileNameXls = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files, *.xl*", MultiSelect:=True)
    If Not IsArray(FileNameXls) Then Exit Sub

    ' set up target
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsTarget = .Sheets("Avg Rate Changes")
    End With
    targetColumn = 4

    ' process each file
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each f In FileNameXls
    
        ' find an empty column
        Do While WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsTarget.Columns(targetColumn)) > 0
            targetColumn = targetColumn + 1
        Loop
        
        ' open source
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(f, ReadOnly:=True)
        With wbSource
            ' copy values to array
            arData = .Worksheets("Avg Rate Changes").Range("G9:G21")
            
            ' replace blanks with 0
            For i = 1 To UBound(arData)
               If arData(i, 1) = "" Then arData(i, 1) = 0
            Next
            
            ' save to target
            wsTarget.Cells(4, targetColumn).Resize(UBound(arData), 1) = arData
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
            n = n + 1
        End With
        
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox n & " files imported", vbInformation
    
End Sub


Where you have set pasteRange, you would define your range using a moving column inside of your loop, e.g.:
'outside of loop
dim colNum as long:  colNum = 5
'inside of loop
dim pasteRange as range:  set pasteRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Avg Rate Changes").Cells(1,colNum)
pasteRange.PasteSpecial
colNum = colNum + 1

This will paste whatever was copied into the first cell in a column through its total used row.
Move your replace outside of the loop so everything that needs changed will happen at once, after.
